# Get class of matlab struct element

Tags: matlab, types

I have a matlab struct that has a sub-element such that when I run

```
class(foo.bar)
```

Gives the error:

```
Error using class
The CLASS function must be called from a class constructor.
```

When I just run `foo.bar`, `ans` gets set several times.

**How can I find out which class `bar` belongs to?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you have a **structure array** as `foo`. Example:

```
>> foo = struct('a',{1 2})
foo = 
1x2 struct array with fields:
    a

>> foo.a
ans =
     1
ans =
     2

>> class(foo.a)
Error using class
The CLASS function must be called from a class constructor. 

>> class(foo(1).a)
ans =
double
```

Note that `foo.a` returns here what is called *a [comma-separated list](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html)*.